# Estimating quantiles of conditional distribution in R

Tags: r, quantile

I'm trying to estimate the 0.90 quantile of a conditional distribution of interval|(duration=250). This is in the data file "oldfaith" in R, in library(alr4). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? If your question is more about the general concept of conditional distributions and estimating their quantiles it might be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I making two guesses but that's alll they are because there is no code to review. That you haven't actually tried anything yet (because you would have gotten errors) and that you want the condition on that variable to be ">=".